# Mostrar opcion seleccionada de combobox con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me llena un combobox con opciones traidas desde una base de datos:

```
<?php

    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "");
    $bd = mysqli_select_db ($conexion, "empresa");

    $destinos = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT nombre FROM destinos");


    echo ("<form action='destino.php' method='POST'>");
echo ("<select name='destinos'>");
while ($dest = mysqli_fetch_array($destinos)) {
    echo "<option value='".$dest['id']."'>".$dest['nombre']."</option>";
}
echo ("</select>");
echo ("<br><br>");
echo ("<input type='submit' value='Buscar'>");
echo ("</form>");


    ?>
```

Y necesito mostrar la opcion seleccionada en "destino.php". Tengo el siguiente codigo en destino.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

     foreach ($_POST['destinos'] as $select)
     {
       echo $select;
     }
   }
?>
```

El cual al igual que este:

```
<?php

$destino = $_POST['destinos'];

echo ("Has seleccionado: ".$destino);


?>
```

No me muestra nada. No me arroja error ni nada por el estilo, pero no me devuelve la opción seleccionada.

Comment: Te faltan las comillas para el atributo value `"<option value='".$dest['id']."'>`,  en una forma solo se manda el valor seleccionado de la opción, tu foreach sobra ya que `$_POST['destinos']` solo contendrá un valor, el de tu opción seleccinada, y para validar si tu variable post existe debe ser `isset($_POST)` porque el índice submit de post no existe como tal.

Comment: Aun asi no me muestra nada.

Comment: La respuesta es muy sencilla, el problema lo tienes en tu consulta sql, ya que en la consulta solo estas mostrando el campo nombre, entonce al hacer el while , tu variable $dest['id']. esta vacia, entonces como esta vacia, por eso es que no te muestra resultado

Comment: No estoy seguro de que esto `$_POST['submit']` contenga algo, ya que POST obtiene los valores leyendo el atributo `name` y en tu formulario no hay ningún elemento que se llame `submit`. Si cambias el código así: `if(isset($_POST['destinos'])) {

     foreach ($_POST['destinos'] as $select)
     {
       echo $select;
     }
   }` debería funcionar. También, como se ha dicho, necesitas incluir el `id` en el `SELECT...` si es que quieres usar dicho valor en el `value` de tus `option`.

Comment: Te imprimen los valores <option> ?